# Trying to add a row from a df to a dtm causes problems

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, naivebayes

I want to transfer the value "Sentiment_2" from the dataset "df_full_mc" into the "dtm dtmNB_df". But when i do so, it shows me the following error: Error in

```
[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "y", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :   replacement has 1256 rows, data has 1257.
```

Here is my line that causes the problem. The Y column gets added but there are only NA cases.

```
dtmNB_df['y'] <- as.factor(df_full_mc[df_full_mc$ID %in% dtmNB$dimnames$Docs,]$Sentiment_2)
```

dtmNB_df has 1257 obs. of 989 variables while
df_full_mc has 1284 obs. of 3 variables.

The observations in dtmNB-df are comments from a YouTube video that i coded (Sentiment_2) and i want to do the Naives-Bayes Approach for supervised machine learning. 
I tried to add the extra column but it didn't work out. Sorry for the question, it's my first time asking questions here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you doing this subselection `df_full_mc[df_full_mc$ID %in% dtmNB$dimnames$Docs,]`? Thats where you have the problem